# The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

Tags: wcf

I'm running some WCF net.tcp services on a high-traffic website.
In my local environment everything worked as expect.
In the production environment, the website works for few minutes then the service throw an exception.
When I stop and start again the service website it works again for few minutes.

Here's the details:

**A TCP error (995: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request) occurred while transmitting data.**

System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.EndRead()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.EndRead()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.ReadAsyncResult.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.TracingConnectionState.ExecuteCallback()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.AsyncReadCallback(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 bytesRead)
System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

**The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request**

Answer (score 0):

I see the same problem on Win8kR2SP1Web:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800703E3): The I/O operation has been     aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E3)
An error occurred while communicating with the remote host. The error code is 0x800703E3.
The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E3)

at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect) 
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ReadEntityCoreSync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) 
at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent() 
at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() 
at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() 
at System.Web.Mvc.HttpRequestExtensions.GetHttpMethodOverride(HttpRequestBase request) 
at System.Web.Mvc.AcceptVerbsAttribute.IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo) 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.All[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelector.RunSelectionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 methodInfos) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedControllerDescriptor.FindAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.FindAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, String actionName) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) 
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() 
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionSt ep.Execute() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

First time in 1 year though ...

Comment: 2nd time ! It is a bug in IIS i think