# The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request in WCF

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I have already seen following questions and their non-working answers.

1. [No matter what I try: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013307/no-matter-what-i-try-the-i-o-operation-has-been-aborted-because-of-either-a-thr)
2. [The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228703/the-i-o-operation-has-been-aborted-because-of-either-a-thread-exit-or-an-applica)
3. [The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339683/the-i-o-operation-has-been-aborted-because-of-either-a-thread-exit-or-an-applica)

I have a console application with which I am stress testing my WCF service. When I make more than 80 simultaneous calls to the service, sometimes it works all fine and sometimes some of the calls fail with following exception.

**Exception Type:** System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

**Message:** The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

**StackTrace:**

at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.HandleReceiveAsyncCompleted()

at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)

at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsyncCompleted(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)

at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)

at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationAsyncFailure(SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)

at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)

at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

I am calling following code using loops :

```
var tcpb = new NetTcpBinding();
TimeSpan timeOutAfter =  new TimeSpan(0, 10,0);
tcpb.OpenTimeout = timeOutAfter;
tcpb.SendTimeout = timeOutAfter;
tcpb.CloseTimeout = timeOutAfter;
tcpb.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;

string address = "net.tcp://" + MYIP + ":" + PORTNUMBER + "/" + PORTTYPE + "/";

ChannelFactory<ServiceName> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ServiceName>(tcpb,address);
var client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
((IClientChannel)client).Open();
//Function Call here
((IClientChannel)client).Close();
channelFactory.Close();
```

Any ideas ans solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should post code if you want peoples help....  Show how you are testing the service.

Comment: @TMcKeown I have added my calling code in my question.

Comment: are you sure you are waiting long enough after the call?  If you execute many concurrent calls then I would guess you could get some lag in response.  Aren't you possibly shutting down the socket too early?

Comment: All my timouts are 10minutes. I am not getting any timeouts in traces.

Comment: ok but I see you calling .Close()...  when is that being called?  Immediately?  As you can see in the stack trace, the error occurs while waiting for a response.

Comment: "All my timeouts" => including on the server? Last time I had this problem someone had changed `receiveTimeout` from 5 minutes to 5 seconds. I've also had this problem due to certificate revocation checks taking too long (externally accessing a resource with a self signed cert but the cert had a revocation server whose address was internal). *When I make more than 80 simultaneous calls to the service* Also keep an eye out for service throttling and the listen backlog.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Yes both service side and the clientside all timeouts are 1o minutes.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I have put throttle of 1000 concurrent calls.

Comment: @TMcKeown My function call goes to database and it just returns 3 rows. I am calling close after this data is retrieved and returned.

Comment: ok, but why does the stack trace refer to AsyncComplete?  Sync calls wouldn't throw that.

Comment: ^^^I'm guessing on that...  i just don't recall seeing Async unless I'm doing Async

Comment: @TMcKeown I assume this is for handling calls in async way. I have used `InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall` on my service code

Comment: It's not uncommon to implement synchronous calls with their asynchronous counterparts ... as long as you know what you're doing, it beats writing the same function twice. It's not like synchronous calls can't use asynchrony -- they just have to be synchronous. How they do that => implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your service can't cope with the 80 concurrent calls.

Look at WCF Throttling to configure the maximum number of concurrent calls your service should support.  There is a good topic on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33362/WCF-Throttling) about this.

Also the default InstanceContextMode of TCP bindings is PerSession and default behavior of WCF is to allow maximum 16 concurrent sessions.  If session mode is not required, you should configure the service to use InstanceContextMode.PerCall.  This is far more scalable than PerSession...